# Error AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

i have this code in java:

```
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {

public AboutFragment(){}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Delete entry")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // continue 
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // do nothing
        }
     })
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
     .show();

    return rootView;
}
```

and error is: 
The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(AboutFragment) is undefined,
ic_dialog_alert cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `AlertDialog.Builder` requires a `Context` and a `Fragment` is not a `Context`. Try `getActivity()` instead of `this`.

Comment: That's a tougher one to answer because there could be a number of reasons. Do you have a file in one of the drawable folders named "ic_dialog_alert.extension"? If it looks like you do, clean your project and see if it works.